# Run mediawiki userOptions script without SSH

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to run the userOptions script for MediaWiki to add a new namespace to the default search namespaces for all existing users. Unfortunately, I don't have shell access to my hosting provider, and to be honest I'm really not at home with using cron jobs.

What's the easiest way for me to run this script on my MediaWiki install:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault#Changing_options_for_existing_users
(sorry, the url won't parse properly)

For instance, is there a php command that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own PHP script. In it, populate the $argv and $argc variables, and then just include the userOptions.php file in your own PHP file.